# c# AspNetCore WebApi - how to tell if json property is set or not on PUT?

Tags: c#, put, asp.net-core-webapi

I have hard time finding the best way to deal with default values, when deserializing json into a class model in my AspNetCore WebApi.

Whenever a client makes a PUT request to the api, how should i figure out if a property was set to null in the request - or not set at all in the request?

At this moment I use the [FromBody] Attribute for deserialization into a class type, along with ModelValidation for requiring fields etc. But once the json request has been deserialized, how can i tell if eg. a "string name" property was explicitly set to null, or not set at all in the json requst, but defaulted to null?

It the case it was not set at all, i don't want to change the state of the actual model being saved in DB, for that property.

The problem arises when a client uses PUT, and a new field has been implemented, which the client does not know about. I don't want clients overwriting a "new" value to null, that they have no intention of setting in the first place.

Is there any standard or best practice for handling this? I can't imagine i'm the only one with this problem. Implementing my own json deserializer, or, implementing versioning for the endpoint for the sake of adding an additional field, seems a bit over the top.. And coordinating a deploy for all the clients at the same time (where the handling of the new property/value is handled), is not an option either.

All suggestions appreciated.

Regards Frederik

Comment: _"I use the [FromBody] Attribute for deserialization into a class type"_, `[FromBody]` attribute is not for deserialization. I'ts for to force Web API to read a simple type from the request body.

Comment: It is not clear what is your expected result. Assuming you have some `DTO` which model binder populates based on the body of your message. The result of the parsing is a `DTO`. It will put `null` for both cases - missed property and null value. Using this `DTO` how do you plan to distinguish this cases? Clever way is to add another version of API with new `DTO` model (inherited from old one with additional properties). If you don't like this - add some flags (`bool IsSet`) in `DTO` and create custom Model Binder which will populate flags for you

Comment: another way - add in DTO parameter for storing client version. New clients will populate its version while old clients will not. If parameter is null or empty - request is from old client

Comment: @SeM Defining [FromBody] in conjunction with a Class Type in the Controller Method, isn't that how you declare the deserialization into the class type??

Comment: @DmitryPavliv Thanks for the input, both approaches seem reasonable to me, will definitely consider those

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not using proper HTTP method and that is source of your problem. HTTP PUT means that you want to overwrite resource at request url with what is in request body. And because C# doesn't have `undefined` then it cannot differentiate `NULL` from not provided property.

If you need to do partial modification then you should use [PATCH](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-core-json-patch-partial-api-updates) instead

Comment: What if you are working on an existing API, and cannot have your clients change METHOD, or change to patch document formats?

How do you find out if a null property was sent, or just defaulted by the model??